# Add a column to a DataFrame after selecting rows based on column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I have a weather forecasting dataset and I am interesd in the columns:

- `period` (values: 1,2,3)
- `temp2m`: corresponds to a temperature 2 meters away from a weather station.

`p1 = new_df.where(new_df.period == 1).select([c for c in df.columns if c in ['period','temp2m']]).show()`

This code for p1 gives the following (first 5):

```
+------+------+
|period|temp2m|
+------+------+
|     0|    12|
|     0|    13|
|     0|    11|
|     0|    13|
|     0|    10|
+------+------+
```

I would like to store the results of `temp2m` as `temp2m_p1` in the main DataFrame `new_df`. Similarly I'd like to add `temp2m_p2` and `temp2m_p2` as well. However I have trouble finding a solution to this problem on https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-add-new-column-to-dataframe/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please always provide a toy example and expected result. Here is mine:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'period': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
                       'temp2m': [12, 13, 12, 20, 21, 22, 18, 18, 16]})
```

```
   period  temp2m
0       1      12
1       1      13
2       1      12
3       2      20
4       2      21
5       2      22
6       3      18
7       3      18
8       3      16
```

I believe you want:

```
for p in new_df['period'].unique():
    new_df[f'temp2m_p{p}'] = new_df['temp2m'].where(new_df['period'] == p)
```

Which results in:

```
   period  temp2m  temp2m_p1  temp2m_p2  temp2m_p3
0       1      12       12.0        NaN        NaN
1       1      13       13.0        NaN        NaN
2       1      12       12.0        NaN        NaN
3       2      20        NaN       20.0        NaN
4       2      21        NaN       21.0        NaN
5       2      22        NaN       22.0        NaN
6       3      18        NaN        NaN       18.0
7       3      18        NaN        NaN       18.0
8       3      16        NaN        NaN       16.0
```

**EDIT** after the comments:

```
df_transformed = pd.concat((new_df[new_df['period'] == p]['temp2m'].rename(f'temp2m_{p}').reset_index(drop=True) for p in new_df['period'].unique()), axis=1)
```

That gives:

```
   temp2m_1  temp2m_2  temp2m_3
0      12      20      18
1      13      21      18
2      12      22      16
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, this gives me an error: TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
Since new_df is a spark dataframe and not a pandas one

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the NaN values ? So that all the values are placed on top (start at index 0) and replace the NaN values by 0 ?

Comment: Ah so you don't care about the old `temp2m` column anymore?

Comment: @user19035064 check my edit at the end

Comment: That's correct. I tried to remove all the NaN values using new_df[new_df['temp2m_p0'].notnull(), ['temp2m_p1.notnull(), etc. up to temp4m_p3]. But the issue here is that it would work for p0 but since the indexes are gone, errors occur since indexation for p1, p2, p3 etc. are gone... And a comparison is needed for each row...

Comment: @user19035064 I see, try the solution at the bottom of my edited answer, see if this is what you need

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That's exactly what I've been looking for.